# Execute Parallelly two different automation script in two diffrent geny motion instances

Tags: robotium, genymotion

I have developed robotium automation script and its running sequentially in single genymotion instance

I want execute Parallelly two different automation script in two diffrent geny motion instances simultaneously

After opened two genymotion instance , i did ...

adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.56.103:5555    device
192.168.56.101:5555    device

I have opened one terminal and exported : export ANDROID_SERIAL=192.168.56.101:5555 , one instance of geny motion

I have opened other terminal and exported other instances ANDROID_SERIAL=192.168.56.103:5555

I have executed the different script in corresponding terminal window but genymotion is not running different script in different instance , its running same script in two instance and generated the report .

Please let me know I want to run two different robotim automation script paralley in genymotion ?

Expecting you idea and solution !

Thanks ,
Muthu Selvan SR

Answer (score 1):

So there are couple parts to this question as far as i can see. It seems like you have the first part sorted which is to have two devices connected to your machine and it seems like you can connect to them via ADB.

The next part is to be able to tell the devices to run the tests, it seems like whatever command you are using (if you could post that it might help) is telling it to run the same tests. Sadly there is no way to auto paraallelise the tests across the two devices so you will have to manually determine the sets of tests to send to each device which can be done in a number of ways.

If you look at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestRunner.html) you can see that there are many ways to filter what tests should be run. What you will want to do is find a way to halve them approximately equal between the two emulators so that you get the desired results. I give an example of doing something like this over at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803435/java-robotium-android-run-same-test-simultaneosly-on-two-different-devices)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **BAT** file (Windows) or **shell script .sh** (UNIX, MAC) which will contain something like the following:

```
adb -s <serial1> shell am instrument -w <package.test>/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner&

adb -s <serial2> shell am instrument -w <package.test>/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

And run your tests. This will run your test on both the devices at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your response , But i am not using adb to run the script , as i mentioned in post I am using spoon to run my scripts from maven